# Angular2 - How to set the ngModel value as the input's value

Tags: angular, data-binding

Component:

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  public error: any;
  currentUser = {};

  constructor(private afService: AF) {
    afService.getCurrentUserInfo().then(currentUserDetails => {
      this.currentUser = currentUserDetails;
    });
  }

  updateUserEntry(fname, lname, phone, bio) {

    this.afService.getCurrentUserInfo().then((user) => {
      let details = [];
      details.push(user);
      console.log(details[0].userID);
      this.afService.updateUserEntry(details[0].userID, fname, lname, phone, bio).then(() => {
        console.log("Updated entry");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
        console.log("error");
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Form:

```
<form>
        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>First Name</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="currentUser.firstName" name="fname" class="form-control" type="text"></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Last Name</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="currentUser.lastName" name="lname" class="form-control" type="text"></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Email</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="currentUser.email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" disabled></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Mobile Phone</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="currentUser.phone" name="phone" class="form-control" type="text"></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Bio</label></dt>
          <dd>
            <textarea [(ngModel)]="currentUser.bio" name="bio" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </dd>
        </dl>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateUserEntry(fname, lname, phone, bio)">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

The function updates a JSON record.  For example it updates the "firstName:" entry with the "fname" ngModel.  The problem is, the ngModel is read as null unless the user modifies value of the input, even though a value already exists with `value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}"`.

How can I set the ngModel to interpret it's value from the actual input's `value=""`?

Comment: Have you tried to do it in *component*: `this.fname = this.currentUser.firstName`? (You can take out value).

Comment: Yeah, I get an error `firstName does not exist on type '{}'`

Comment: It is typescript error, that gets resolved if you set proper type to `currentUser` or atleast set type `any`. `public currentUser: any;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not use different variable such as `fname` , directly pass `currentUser.firstName` for ngModel.

```
<input 
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="currentUser.firstName" 
  name="fname" 
  class="form-control">
```

But if my understanding is wrong and you want **to initialize `fname` with `currentUser.firstName`** then do that in the component.

```
this.fname = currentUser.firstName
```

and in html

```
 <input 
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="fname" 
      name="fname" 
      class="form-control">
```

Dont use both ngModel and value at the same time they are contradicting in case of text type (check comment below) .

**Update after complete code snippet**

To make your current code working do these changes :

- give type to `currentUser` like

  `public currentUser:any = {};`
- Remove params in `updateUserEntry` , but get the value from `this.currentUser`

  ```
  this.afService.updateUserEntry(
      details[0].userID, 
      this.currentUser.fname,
      this.currentUser.lname,
      this.currentUser.phone, 
      this.currentUser.bio)
  ```

**Better way**

But I believe you are complicating it . In my opinion never use ngModel unless you need two way data binding. Instead use FormGroup [Example from thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: *"Dont use both ngModel and value at the same time they are contradicting."* ... not always, in inputs `type="radio"` they're needed, for example.

Comment: Cool, will update my answer to be specific to text inputs.

Comment: I was able to remove the `value=""` and replace the ngModel with `currentUser.firstName` but I'm still getting the error when trying to run the action.  The value being passed through the form into the function is being read as empty which returns an error.

Comment: Can you give complete related code , html and component